# Is good practice for view sending param by assign to controller property?

Tags: codeigniter

For sending param to view, document in CodeIgniter use as following:

```
  $data['name'] = $this->name;
  $data['color'] = $this->color;
  $this->load->view('you_view',$data);//Load view with $data param
```

But currently i use like this:

```
        //Controller file
        $this->params = [Big Object or Array ];//Here I assigned my OJBECT or Array to controller property PARAMS
        $this->load->view('you_view');//***** Wthout send with load view*******

        //View file
        $var_dump($this->params);//Notice after I print_r( $this) i found that it is current controller, that why i use without sending params during load view, but i afraid any problem or make my system slow.
```

Answer (score 0):

In many different ways you can pass variables to the view, for example through controller as you did, then through config file, model, language file, or defining a variables with define(), but then the point of MVC model was to separate data, logic and design, so i don't thing your way is a bad way, just not in the spirit of idea of MVC. Do you get any better performance?

Comment: I don't know the way i did good performance or not, I just notice that when i print_r($this) on view but it is a belong to current controller properties if this point if i assign a big data i afraid it to much allocated memories.

Comment: Don't worry about that, data is not duplicating, it is handled pretty well by php itselves, so the data will be in the memory still as it was, just the references it will be changed.